# SecondaryItem в стандартной Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Я использую стандартную `NavigationDrawer` из шаблона *Android Studio*.
Каким образом в нем можно реализовать отдельное меню, например для кнопки "настройки" расположенной снизу, отдельно от остального меню?

Допустим, с помощью библиотеки от [Mike Penz](http://portfolio.mikepenz.com/) это делается довольно легко, с помощью метода `addDrawerItems()`, да и есть примеры создания такого меню... Но примеров работы со стандартным шаблоном я не нашел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без существенных изменений кода в `NavigationDrawer` из шаблона *Android Studio* так сделать нельзя потому, что в шаблоне наипростейшая реализация - `ListView` выводит список пунктов. Данный шаблон скорее для примера и каркаса, чем для реального использования ..

Можно поступить следующим образом:

1. Использовать готовую библиотеку, лучшая здесь как раз Майка Пенза - самое разумное и эффективное решение
2. Использовать новый виджет из библиотек поддержки *support:design* - [`NavigationView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html). [Пример использования](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/).
3. Делать кастомный адаптер для `ListView`, который будет реализовывать нужный вид.
4. Вместо `ListView` использовать `Fragment` - это дает самую большую гибкость в реализации, но и самое заморочное.

Никаких особых примеров для работы с таким простым драйвером и не требуется - простейший `ListView` выводит список пунктов, какие тут нужны примеры? Никаких дополнительных методов для расширения функционала он не реализует.